# Alphanumeric validation error when german language is used

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

In an application which is intended for **germany** ,am writing some **webservices** i have to apply some validation rules for username ,password etc.. like **alphanumeric**,special charecters not supported etc.. i have used regular expression to achive this but it fails,it works fine for english language,but **it  does not support German language**, how can i tackle this issue.

Any help will be appreciated...`preg_match("#.*^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$#", $string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the 'u' modifier for UTF-8 (whose encoding you should be using for international applications). Secondly, if you are trying to allow umlauts, etc. within the [a-zA-Z] block, you can add the specific characters you want using escape sequences as follows:

individually:

```
preg_match( "/\x{00FC}/u" , 'ü' ); // 1
```

or in a group:

```
preg_match('/^[\x{00DF}\x{00E4}\x{00C4}\x{00F6}\x{00D6}\x{00FC}\x{00DC}]+$/u', 'ßäÄöÖüÜ'); // 1
```

...or just use the word letter match `\w` (noting that this will also allow numbers and underscore and other international characters which can serve as word letters).

```
preg_match( "/\w/u" , 'ü' ); // 1
```

(I'm not sure what you are doing with the `^` in the middle of the expression, btw, without an 'm' modifier.)